# How to Post data to other company using their API using Odoo 12?

Tags: xml, python-3.x, python-requests, odoo, odoo-12

I have an API of one company to where I have to **post** my data from odoo. 
I want to use the requests module for this. But I don't know if it is applicable or not in Odoo. There are some data I have to post like username, password, invoice number, total sales, etc.

How can I send data to an external API? The data has to be sent in JSON format.

**And what is the other way of sending data from odoo to other API?**

I have a button in invoice form when that button is clicked the data has to be posted and get response message.
I have tried this.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import datetime
import requests
import logging
from odoo import models, fields, api


logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s',
    datefmt='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S',
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    filename='logs.txt'
)

logger = logging.getLogger('ird')


class invoice_ird(models.Model):


    _inherit = "account.invoice"


    def send_bill_ird(self):

        payload = {
            'username': "Test_CBMS",
            'password': "test@321",
            'seller_pan': f"{self.company_id.vat}",
            'buyer_pan': f"{self.partner_id.vat}",
            'buyer_name': f"{self.partner_id.parent_id}",
            'fiscal_year': "2076.077",
            'invoice_number': f"{self.number}",
            'invoice_date': f"{self.date_invoice}",
            'total_sales': self.amount_total,
            'taxable_sales_vat': self.amount_untaxed,
            'vat': self.amount_tax,
            'excisable_amount': 0,
            'excise': 0,
            'taxable_sales_hst': 0,
            'hst': 0,
            'amount_for_esf': 0,
            'esf': 0,
            'export_sales': 0,
            'tax_exempted_sales': 0,
            'isrealtime': True,
            'datetimeclient': datetime.datetime.now(),
        }
        r = requests.post('http://103.1.92.174:9050/api/bill',     json=payload)
        logger.info(f'Response Messages: {r}, {r.status_code}')
        #print(r)
        #print(r.text)
```

Why doesn't my ***logs.txt*** file is created and how can I see my response message? Is there any best way to work?

My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="invoice_to_ird" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">inovice.to.ird</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath position="after" expr="//form[@class = 'o_invoice_form']/header/button[@name = 'action_invoice_draft']">
                <button class="oe_highlight" name="send_bill_ird" type="action" string="Upload To IRD" attrs="{'invisible':[('state', '!=','paid')]}" />
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Comment: What is your question ? Is the log issue or POST not working? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: My question is to post data to other company using their api, from my odoo. I have tried that code and I have tried to create log file so I can see what response message is but I don't know where to see my response messages. Is requests method works in Odoo. @Kris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you trying to send them dictionary instead of json data. To fix this change

`r = requests.post('http://103.1.92.174:9050/api/bill', json=payload)`

to

`r = requests.post('http://103.1.92.174:9050/api/bill', data=json.dumps(payload))`

Comment: How to see the response code as I cannot create my own log file?

Comment: Or do you know how to post data from odoo to api?

Comment: there's two ways.if you are debagging, you can `import extensions` and after request add `raise exctensions.ValidationError('%s, %s' % (r, r.status_code))` so it's call popup and show you data. Or you can add `with open('resopnse.txt', 'a') as f: f.write('%s, %s\n' % (r, r.status_code))`. And it will create this file in your project dir

Comment: Is that `import exceptions` or `import extensions`, I didn't get it @Artem. If it is `import extensions` what it does?

Comment: oh, sorry it's `import exceptions`

Comment: It's not working, I only get 200 success response code. No other response code.

Comment: maybe it's not odoo? try to find request which gives you another status_code and send it from odoo